# Copy object to an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, list, object

I am trying to copy an object `userinfo` into an array. I keep getting undefined when I try to console log the new array. Any help will be appreciated!

JS:

```
var JSONstring = [{
  "name": "test",
  "properties": {
    "age": "19r",
    "userinfo": {
      "city": "Dallas",
      "state": "Texas"
    }
  }
}];

$(document).ready(function() {
  var userinfo = {};
  for (var i = 0; i < JSONstring.length; i++) {
    var user = JSONstring[i].properties.userinfo;
    if (user === undefined) {
      continue;
    } else if (userinfo[user] === undefined) {
      userinfo[user] = [];
      userinfo[user].push(i);
    } else {
      userinfo[user].push(i);
    }
  }
  console.log(userinfo[0]);
});
```

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dr8hka6a/3/)**

Comment: `userinfo[user]` doesn't make a whole lot of sense, `user` is either undefined or an object. object keys are always  strings.

Comment: So there are a few problems with object types in your example. Your JSONstring var is an object, it does not have a .length member. Your userinfo "array" is also an object.

Comment: Please not that the variable name `JSONstring` is extremely misleading since the value of the variable is an array, not a string (containing JSON). Calling JavaScript objects "JSON" is a (unfortunately) common mistake.

Comment: @FelixKling ok will keep that in mind

Comment: @Ken: NVM then :)

Comment: @KevinB what should I use then?

Comment: @user4756836 dunno. what do you want the key in your object to be? i'd suggest using whatever that is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually you have several problems in your current code:

- Writing `userinfo[user]` is incorrect, if you want to access `user`property of `userinfo`object you need to give it a string like  `userinfo["user"]` or just directly `userinfo.user`.
- In the end you are trying to log `userinfo[0]` which is `undefined`
  because `userinfo` is an `object` and not an `array` you need to
  change it to : `console.log(userinfo.user[0])`.
- If you want to store the `user` object in the array you should replace `push(i)` with `push(user)`.

**Demo:**

I tried to refactor your code so it makes sense, here's what you need:

```js
var JSONstring = [{
  "name": "test",
  "properties": {
    "age": "19r",
    "userinfo": {
      "city": "Dallas",
      "state": "Texas"
    }
  }
}];

$(document).ready(function() {
  var userinfo = {};
  for (var i = 0; i < JSONstring.length; i++) {
    var user = JSONstring[i].properties.userinfo;
    if (!user) {
      continue;
    } else if (!userinfo.user) {
      userinfo.user = [];
      userinfo.user.push(user);
    } else {
      userinfo.user.push(user);
    }
  }
  console.log(userinfo.user[0]);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**Note:**

The condition in the if block `if (userinfo[user] === undefined)` can simply be written `if(!userinfo.user)`

Comment: Why is the console.log coming as 0 now?

Comment: Because it takes `i` in the loop, we should `push(user)`, I edited my answer.